# How to chain raw SQL queries in Rails OR how to return an ActiveRecord_Relation from a raw SQL query in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite, database-connection

How can I run a raw sql query and get an `ActiveRecord_Relation` instance returned?

On a sqlite3 db and Rails 4.2, `ActiveRecords::Base.exec_query(sql)` returns an `ActiveRecord_Result` instance. `ActiveRecords::Base.execute(sql)` returns an array. This is troublesome because I cannot run subsequent "ActiveRecord queries" or raw sql queries on the returned objects.

More generally, I would like to know how to chain "complex" sql queries in Rails. By complex I mean I could not figure out a way to do it through the "ORM methods" given by ActiveRecords. And by chaining I mean I would like to break it down in several SQL queries, for performance reasons. Example: I just want to run the big heavy first SQL query once, store the result and then run lighter sql queries depending on the user behavior.

I am currently trying to optimize a database visualization through [dataTables](https://datatables.net/) implemented with server-side-processing. The server has to run an unnecessarily complex SQL query every time the user interacts with the table because I could not break it down in simpler queries. I looked at the following questions but could not figure out a satisfying solution:

[Rails raw SQL example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824453/rails-raw-sql-example)

[Convert Array#select to active record query in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215170/convert-arrayselect-to-active-record-query-in-rails-4)

[Hash/Array to Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830951/hash-array-to-active-record)

Comment: How did you solve?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a way to get an ActiveRecord_Relation from raw_sql.
It works best if you actually have a model matching the fields you're trying to retrieve, but as you can see with test_attribute, any data will be loaded.

```rb
# Just an example query, any query should be ok
query = <<-SQL
  SELECT *, TRUE AS test_attribute
  FROM users
  WHERE sign_in_count < 10
SQL
relation = User.select('*').from("(#{query}) AS users")

relation.class
# User::ActiveRecord_Relation

relation.first.test_attribute
# true
```

Comment: Wow, this provided me an excellent way of converting some find_by_sql functions that return arrays to active record relations. I would x10 this if possible.

Comment: I am getting this error (Object doesn't support #inspect) is it not possible in Postgres ? Thank you!

Comment: @ShilpiAgrawal This was written and works in postgres yes, your error clearly is not sql related...